# Entity Framework Migrations Intercept Create/Drop table

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

EF Migrations: Add-Migration identifies the tables, fields to be added, removed, updated.
I want to intercept these methods to write some custom login to Create Table, Drop Table. And that in turn will generate the migration code automatically.
Is there a way to do that?

When I add a table, I want to add an article for replication in publisher database. Hope it is possible to add this automatically.

Thanks

Comment: You can customize the SQL Generator as described here: http://romiller.com/2012/01/16/customizing-code-first-migrations-provider/ Instead of CreateIndexOperation use CreateTableOperation. Another example: https://andy.mehalick.com/2014/02/06/ef6-adding-a-created-datetime-column-automatically-with-code-first-migrations/

Comment: Same question in EF Core. Anyone?